# Google Language Translator plugin wordpress change language in select box

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I installed Google Language Translator plugin and i have a trouble about select box i need to change language in this select box to English but now my select box is in Thai language. I have tried to edit in `google-language-translator.php` but i can't solve it.

The error:

[image: my problem pic]

Comment: nor me i cant solve this riddle either.

Comment: check your plugin settings or reinstall it.

Comment: @devpro i already checked so many times and reinstall doesn't fix this

Comment: @tonpsl, what did you check? did you check your language setting??

Comment: Have you contacted the author of the plugin?

Comment: @devpro yes, i checked in setting>general>site language it's English. and i have tried substitute another language but it's not work.

Comment: @tonpsl, your original language set as Chinese Traditional.

Comment: @devpro i changed to English already.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix, try to inspect element in a browser and try to delete the thai language or, all other languages except English and click save to set the language to English.

This will work, but it's not a complete solution.

Comment: yes, but this is not complete solution. i think some line in google-language-translator.php will fixed this but i can't find out where the code work.

Comment: I did not look into the code. If you want to fix this, contact the developer of the plugin.

I only gave you a temporarily fix.